# Regex expression to return a leading string upto (but not including) a second string

Tags: c#, regex

Given the expression:

> "C:\Nova6\Nursing_Desk\bin\Debug"

What regex expression will return the leading string up to (but not including) "Nursing Desk"? That is I want:

> "C:\Nova6"

to be returned.

I do get that

> /^(.*?)abc/

Where abc = "Nursing_Desk" is the general format, but how do I substitute different values for abc?

Please note, I would like to be able to substitute other strings to "search up to" into the regex expression. That is, both the string to be searched and the characters to search for will not be known until runtime. Also both strings may contain spaces.

Visual Studio 2015; .Net 4.6.1 ; C#

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in `C#`

```
string pattern = "^(.*?)(?=\\\\" + abc + ")";
```

*C# Code*

```
string abc = "Nursing_Desk"; //<-- You can use any value of abc in here or take it as input from user
string input = "C:\\Nova6\\Nursing_Desk\bin\\Debug";
string pattern = "^(.*?)(?=\\\\" + abc + ")"; //Concatenating the pattern with content of abc
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

Match match = rgx.Match(input);

if (match.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/WMaxGX)**

If you are interested in finding any string, you can use

```
string pattern = "^(.*?)(?=" + abc + ")";
```

Comment: Thanks. I was staring at this for the last several hours. Your quick response is outstanding!

Comment: @AlanWayne glad, it helped you